# Fade in text under cascading images

Tags: html, css, fadein

I'm trying to get text to appear under these 4 images when hovered on without them changing position, and also make these images clickable (hyperlink).

At the moment the images are in the position I'd like them, but when I hover over them they reposition themselves so that the rest of them lie under the first image, and then the text appears to the right of the images. What am I doing wrong?

I'd also like for there to be a body of text wrapped underneath these images.

Here's the CSS file (fadeintext.css)

```
#ex3 
{ width: 1280px; height: 256px; line-height: 0px; color: transparent; font-size: 50px; font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 300; text-transform: uppercase; -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease; -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease; -o-transition: all 0.5s ease; }
#ex3:hover { line-height: 256px; color: #575858; } #ex3 img{ float: left; margin: 0 15px; }
```

The HTML page:

```
<html><head>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="description">
 
<title>REDACTED</title>
 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="fadeintext.css">
 
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
 
<style type="text/css"></style></head>
</head>
<div id="ex3">
        <img src="best/instagram.png"><p>Instagram</p>
        <img src="best/twitter.png"><p>Twitter</p>
        <img src="best/gplus.png"><p>Google+</p>
        <img src="best/steam.png"><p>Steam</p>
    </div>
</html>
```

And here's the page and the CSS stylesheet together http://www.REDACTED/

If someone could kindly tell me what I should do, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/dx4M9/2/)?

HTML:

```
<div id="ex3">
    <div> 
        <img src="http://www.example.com/best/instagram.png" />
        <p>Instagram</p>
    </div>    
    <div>     
        <img src="http://www.example.com/best/twitter.png"/>
        <p>Twitter</p>
    </div>        
    <div>     
        <img src="http://www.example.com/best/gplus.png"/>
        <p>Google+</p>
    </div>    
    <div>     
        <img src="http://www.example.com/best/steam.png" />
        <p>Steam</p>
    </div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#ex3 {
    width: 1280px; 
    height: 256px; 
    line-height: 0px; 
    color: transparent; 
    font-size: 50px; 
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-weight: 300; 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
}

#ex3 div:hover { 
    line-height: 0px; 
    color: #575858; 
}

p {
    text-align: center;
}

#ex3 div { 
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 15px; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease; 
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease; 
}

#ex3 div:nth-of-type(2) { 
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#ex3 div:nth-of-type(3) { 
    margin-top: 100px;
}

#ex3 div:nth-of-type(4) { 
    margin-top: 150px;
}
```

Comment: That works nicely, but I'm still trying to get it so that each image has it's own hover text, so for example if you hover over the first image, it will display the text associated with the first image.

Comment: Brilliant! It's working nicely now, but I can't seem to get text in underneath these images. It just appears on the far right hand side of the last image (best/steam.png). Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Not entirely. My apologies for not being specific, but I'd like the text to be in columns underneath each image.

Comment: That's the idea, but the text should be there to stay, without the need to hover to read the text in the column. Of course leaving a space between the image and the column for the hover text.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change your HTML structure and wrap each image and associated text in an element.

I've used the figure / figcaption structure but it's easily adaptable.

**[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/67c15f4c970d9c87cb97af5d7887e1eb)**